# c++ overloading >> operator

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I want to add `>>` overloading to my class but when I compile it, the compiler gives me this error:

```
In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const Dogru&)':
[Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' (operand types are
        'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'const int')
```

I made `<<` overloading without problems, but with `>>` it is not working.

The part of my code:

```
    class Dogru{
    private:
        int yon_x, yon_y, yon_z;
    public:
        friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, const Dogru &dog);
    };
    istream& operator>> (istream &in, const Dogru &dog){
        in >> dog.yon_x;
        in >> dog.yon_y;
        in >> dog.yon_z;    
        return in;
    }

    int main(){
         Dogru al;
         cout << "Enter al's x y z:";
         cin >> al;
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't put the read value into a `const` object. Remove the `const`:

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, Dogru &dog){
    in >> dog.yon_x;
    in >> dog.yon_y;
    in >> dog.yon_z;    
    return in;
}
```

Details: `const` means "my code will not alter this variable". But the whole point of an input operation *is* to alter the variable.

You can overload `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Dogru&);` just fine because an output operation does not need to alter the given variable.`

Comment: oh I really forgot it .Thx much

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the state of `dog` so

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, const Dogru &dog)
                                // ^^ const should be removed
```

Use `const` reference for overloading `<<` operator